# find page source data using pyautogui in python

Tags: python, selenium, urllib, pyautogui

Is it possible to save files using code

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')

when window is minimized.

basically it's a json source file in browser response.

I'm trying to save this response data into json file, but once I minimize the browser it fails to save.

If not possible then please share any alternatives if possible only using pyautogui in python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard shortcuts are keys or combinations of keys that provide an alternate way to do something you'd typically do with a mouse.

Hence, if a window is minimized, then the scope of its activity is also not there and the mouse or the keyboard shortcuts can only interact with other windows that are either open or already in focus.

So to conclude, if a window is minimized, neither the mouse buttons and pointer nor the keyboard shortcuts(in your case the 'Ctrl+S') would work.